# How to show time zone in display time on Windows

Tags: windows-8, date-time

I'm using an editor that **can insert date time values** into files.

It uses Windows (mostly 7 and 8.1, in my current use) as the source of the timedate string.

I'd like to use **ISO 8601** style date times.  I'm currently getting strings like "**2014-01-30 17:58:50**".

The windows time string settings (t and tt) give me a way to put "a.m." into the string, but no equivalent, that I can see, for 24 hour clock settings.  I'd like to see something like "**2014-01-30 17:58:50+11**".

**Is there a way to define the windows system time string, to include zone information?**

Answer (score 0):

As for the time zone information, I use this as a variable, add to your output.  Alternatively it is available from the registry but the syntax is longer.

```
$TIMEZONE = tzutil.exe /g
$TIMEZONE
```

Result

```
China Standard Time
```